# delete CIDR with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cidr

How to delete lines containing CIDR notation with "sed" command?

Example file:

```
127.0.0.0/8
169.254.0.0/16
187.187.193.62
187.187.193.165
240.0.0.0/4
```

expected result sed ??? file > newfile:

```
187.187.193.62
187.187.193.165
```

Comment: If grep is an option: `grep -vF / file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple **sed** approach:

```
sed -i '/\/[0-9]*$/d' file
```

Comment: @randomir, my first attempt was exactly as so, but decided to add some "insuring" detail for accuracy

Comment: Assuming each line is either a valid IP, or a CIDR range, testing just for slash should be sufficient. If not, you should test for the complete pattern.

Comment: @randomir, that's the moment that the OP could elaborate

Comment: @user4839775, does this `sed '/\//d' file > new` work?